# CCJumpTo and CCJumpBy height parameter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

The classes `CCJumpTo` and `CCJumpBy` have the method: `actionWithDuration:position:height:jumps:`. I don´t understand what´s the true meaning of the height parameter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I presume it's the jump height, no?

Comment: I also thought that, but when you decrease the y of the position parameter the height parameter gets affected somehow, also decreases. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That method gives you not only jump functionality, but also moving.
Position what you set needed for moving object, but not for simple moving. You can set moving with small jumps (like a ball) or moving throw one jump.

So

Duration - duration of moving action.
Position - target position for moving (CCJumpTo) or shift (CCJumpBy).
Height - height of jump.
Jumps - number of jumps throw moving animation.

If you need only one jump without moving - you can simply call:

```
    [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:jumpDuration position:ccp(0.0, 0.0) height:jumpHeight jumps:1.0]
```